# Parity POA: the validator's are not getting paid in ETH for sealing blocks

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, parity-io

I am working on creating Parity private Blockchain, however,the validator's are not getting paid in ETH for sealing blocks. 
I use this command line to check the balance:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBalance","params":["0x0037a6b811ffeb6e072da21179d11b1406371c63", "latest"],"id":1}' http://172.0.0.1:8545
```

I want to ask how can I fix these problem.

```
{
"name": "Testnet",
    "engine": {
    "authorityRound": {
        "params": {
            "gasLimitBoundDivisor": "0x400",
            "stepDuration": "2",
            "validators" : {
                "list": [ "0xa19b0e4f7ba1d5f74960c0aad794756a0a16eab4", "0x9c8f23e0a9377bd98322f8333142eadbaed200e8", "0x2f2033e303d4bf17403521e0c1830bac4ba09323", "0xe883b46f02ecd0e624082fe6ff12af0337ba0cde", "0xbdc56eb866933e7ba827fa293d4545ef2a350ce2"]
            }
        }
    }
},

"params": {
    "maximumExtraDataSize": "0x20",
    "minGasLimit": "0x1388",
    "gasLimitBoundDivisor": "0x400",
    "networkID" : "0x11"
},
"genesis": {
    "seal": {
        "authorityRound": {
            "step": "0x0",
            "signature": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
        }
    },
    "difficulty": "0x20000",
    "gasLimit": "0x1312D00"
},
"accounts": {
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "ecrecover", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 3000, "word": 0 } } } },
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "sha256", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 60, "word": 12 } } } },
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000003": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "ripemd160", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 600, "word": 120 } } } },
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000004": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "identity", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 15, "word": 3 } } } },
    "0x00Ea169ce7e0992960D3BdE6F5D539C955316432": { "balance": "1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376" }  
}
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You are querying the wrong balance:

- `0x0037a6b811ffeb6e072da21179d11b1406371c63` is not in your validator node list.

You only specified the following validators:

- ```
  "list": [
      "0xa19b0e4f7ba1d5f74960c0aad794756a0a16eab4", 
      "0x9c8f23e0a9377bd98322f8333142eadbaed200e8",
      "0x2f2033e303d4bf17403521e0c1830bac4ba09323",
      "0xe883b46f02ecd0e624082fe6ff12af0337ba0cde", 
      "0xbdc56eb866933e7ba827fa293d4545ef2a350ce2"
  ]
  ```

Try to get the balance of these nodes.